# Least squares in $\mathbb{F}_2$ using pseudo-inverse

Tags: finite-fields, matrix-equations, least-squares

Consider the following matrices over $\mathbb{F}_2$

$$A = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]\ ,\ x = \left[\begin{matrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3 \end{matrix}\right]\ ,\ b = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{matrix}\right]$$

I'm trying to find the vector $x$ that minimizes the hamming distance between $Ax$ and $b$. From doing some reading online, I've discovered that the assignment $x$ which minimizes $||Ax-b||^2$ (pretty much equivalent to the hamming distance) is given by $x=A^+b$, where $A^+$ is the [Moore-Penrose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse) pseudo-inverse, a matrix which satisfies $AA^+A = A$ (and a few other conditions). For the above example, this matrix is

$$A^+ = \left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 0 & 0\end{matrix}\right] \implies x=A^+b = \left[\begin{matrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 1 \end{matrix}\right]$$

However, $Ax = \left[\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]^T$, which has hamming distance 3 from $b$. You can trivially find other solutions through brute force (such as $x=\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]^T \implies Ax=\left[\begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \end{matrix}\right]^T$) which only have hamming distance 1 from $b$.

What's going wrong, and how can I get least squares to work in $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: I don't really see why least squares should work outside an inner product space, let alone a space not over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: That's fair enough I guess, but the original problem is still well-defined, if you consider minimizing Hamming distance as an analogue to least squares. I'm wondering if any common techniques can still be applied, or if it requires new techniques.

Comment: It is equivalent to find the vector in Ax-b with minimal weight, which can be hard in general.